# In App.get i would like to have two different responses (channels)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, publish-subscribe

I am using expressjs and in app.get, I would like to have a list of responses with one url (app.get). basically i get an error when it tries to run res.writeHead() for the second time. This is the error:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:503:11)
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:510:3)
at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:225:21)
at SSEChannel.subscribe (/home/pouya/Documents/nodejs/pubsub/sse-pubsub.js:39:9)
at app.get (/home/pouya/Documents/nodejs/pubsub/server.js:57:29)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/pouya/Documents/nodejs/pubsub/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/home/pouya/Documents/nodejs/pubsub/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (/home/pouya/Documents/nodejs/pubsub/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/pouya/Documents/nodejs/pubsub/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /home/pouya/Documents/nodejs/pubsub/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
```

Any Idea, how I can solve this?

So, 
This is my part of broker that is handling a SSE channel:

```
app.get('/bob/sub/*', (req, res, next) => {

const channel = req.params['0'];
if(channel.includes(multilevel_indicator) || channel.includes(singlelevel_indicator))
{
    for (let [sseChannel, value] of Object.entries(sseChannels)) {
        if(wildcard(sseChannel, channel))
        {
            console.log("wildcard sub", sseChannel);
            sseChannels[sseChannel].subscribe(req, res);
        }
    }
}}
```

This is part of my subscribe function

```
   subscribe(req, res) {
    const c = {req, res};
    c.req.socket.setNoDelay(true);
    c.res.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
        "Cache-Control": "s-maxage="+(Math.floor(this.options.maxStreamDuration/1000)-1)+"; max-age=0; stale-while-revalidate=0; stale-if-error=0",
        "Connection": "keep-alive"
    });
    return c;
}
```

and this is my part of sse client:

```
const es = new EventSource("/bob/sub/#");
    console.log(channelName);
    es.addEventListener('myEvent', ev => {
        const data = JSON.parse(ev.data);
    });
```

Comment: Please provide a small verifiable code example.

Comment: @DomenikReitzner You can check it now

Comment: Ok, you can only write the head once. After head content HAS to follow. If you are not sure which head you want to send, than put it in a variable and overwrite it, before you do `res.writeHead`

Comment: @DomenikReitzner ok, but is there a way to check if the res already has a writehead or not?

Comment: yes, only write it once :D

Comment: @DomenikReitzner haha sorry, that was silly. Thanks a lot